# how to connect output of one entity with the input of other entity

Tags: vhdl

my vhdl code is as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


ENTITY pc IS PORT(
d   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
clk : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock.
q   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0) -- output
);
END pc;

ARCHITECTURE description OF pc IS
BEGIN
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
            q <= d;
    else
             q <= x"00000000";
    end if;
end process;
END description;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity ins_memory is
port( inp1 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  oup1 : out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
  clk : in std_logic);
end ins_memory;

architecture behv1 of ins_memory is
type ROM_Array is array (0 to 14)
of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
constant Content: ROM_Array := (
0 => "00001",
-- Suppose ROM has
1 => "00010",
-- prestored value
2 => "00011",
-- like this table
3 => "00100",
--
4 => "00101",
--
5 => "00110",
--
6 => "00111",
--
7 => "01000",
--
8 => "01001",
--
9 => "01010",
--
10 => "01011",
--
11 => "01100",
--
12 => "01101",
--
13 => "01110",
--
14 => "01111",
--
OTHERS => "11111"
--
);

component pc IS PORT(
d   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0) :=x"00000000";
clk : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock.
q   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
);
END component;

begin
D1: pc port map(q=> inp1,clk=>clk,d=>open);
process(inp1,clk)
begin
oup1<= Content (conv_integer(inp1));
end process;

end behv1;
```

basically, I trying to connect 'signal q' which is output of entity pc with 'signal inp1' which is input of entity ins_memory, but I am getting following error when I tried it in simple way

**D1: pc port map(q=> inp1,clk=>clk,d=>open);
  Updating port BEHV1:INP1 of mode IN is not allowed.
  Please verify the port mapping for correctness.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inp1` port is the **input** of the top level entity (`memory`), and you are trying to connect it to the **output** of the internal component (`pc`). So it is going to be driven from two directions - from outside of the top-level module, and by this internal component. Which is obviously illegal.